# The Best Solution for an AWS Mobile App, DynamoDB, & S3 Scenario

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am planning a game app for mobile devices. Users will log into the game using their existing social media account to streamline data capture. Company B would like to directly save player data and scoring information from the mobile app to a DynamoDS table named Score Data When a user saves their game the progress data will be stored to the Game state S3 bucket.

What is the best approach for storing data to DynamoDB and S3?

> Option 1: Use an EC2 Instance that is launched with an EC2 role providing access to the Score Data DynamoDB table and the GameState S3 bucket that communicates with the mobile app via web services.
>
> Option 2: Use temporary security credentials that assume a role providing access to the Score Data DynamoDB table and the Game State S3 bucket using web identity federation.

Many architects I talked to Option 1 is the right one.  But according to AWS doco, it appears Option2 can be valid too. Any inputs would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would strongly consider Option #2 using Amazon Cognito to provide temporary credentials to your users that enable them to directly and specifically access DynamoDB and S3.

Generally speaking, you need to:

1. Create a new Cognito Identity Pool and set up 2 IAM roles -- one for authenticated users and one for unauthenticated users (optional). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/getting-started/?platform=ios
2. Authenticate a user via your own authentication provider or via external providers like Facebook, Twitter, etc., and then use Cognito to create temporary credentials for them. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/external-providers/
3. Use the credentials to access DynamoDB and/or S3. Your AWS resources will be protected as long as you set up your IAM roles appropriately. For example, you can give fine grained access to your DynamoDB table so that users cannot access rows that don't belong to them. See the following link for more details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/iam-roles/

The Cognito developer guide is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/.